# GCP KMS to store credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms, secretsmanager

The answer below looks skeptical to me. Cloud KMS encrypts data and returns the encrypted ciphertext. Cloud KMS does not store the secret, only the keys to encrypt/decrypt.

Shouldn't the Secret Manager be a right choice?

[image]

Comment: I would use a Secret Manager

Comment: I agree to @al-dann , use this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/configuring-secret-manager) to enable Secrete Manager API.